# Compare 2 arrays -one contains strings, the other contains numbers. Sum numbers of repeated strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have 2 arrays. Let's say

```
categories = ["hotels", "transfers","food","transfers"] 
amounts = [1500, 250, 165, 150]
```

I would like to generate an object that outputs an object...

```
result = {hotels: 1500, transfers: 400, food: 165}
```

The function should loop over categories, populate the result object, adding the categories' unique elements as object keys, and the amounts as values. The function should also add the amounts of the repeated keys.

I have tried several things like 2 nested for each on the arrays, for loops, ... but I can't figure out anything that works ...

Comment: This should be easy using array methods. Have you made any attempts using any of those?

Comment: ```let d = {};
categories.forEach((c,i)=>{
d[c] = amounts[i]+ (d[c]||0);
})```

Comment: Can you please elaborate `The function should also add the amounts of the repeated keys.` do you want count of repated keys as one key value pair like 'repeatedKeys:0'?

Comment: Hi Prasad. I mean, if the string "transfers" is repeated, the object should add the amounts corresponding to that key ( 250 + 150).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the index of both arrays always in sync, you can do it like:

```
const categories = ["hotels", "transfers","food","transfers"];
const amounts = [1500, 250, 165, 150];
const result = {};

categories.forEach((category, index) => {
  const doesKeyExist = !!result[category];
  const amount = amounts[index];
  const correctAmount = doesKeyExist ? result[category] + amount : amount;

  result[category] = correctAmount;
}
```

this will result in what you expect:

```
result = {hotels: 1500, transfers: 400, food: 165}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ricardo. 
Yes, by construction, both arrays are always in sync 
It works perfectly